# Webscraping Wikipedia Chapters

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning
is the Page i want to scrape.
Now the first subchapter starts from "Artificial intelligence", the first h3 tag and the last one is "Statistical Physics", after that another h2 occurs, so another chapter begins. Thats my endpoint.
My final goal is to create a pandas DataFrame with the columns being the chapter content(the text), the links(hrefs) and the footnotes. The rows are the subchapters, so "Artificial intelligence, "Data mining" etc.
Im new to webscraping so i only now the basics. Initially i started off by finding the first h3, then i would get the information of the p tags. The problem now is, how do i do it that i find the first h3, get the information i need from the following p, put that information in the first row columns, AND THEN go on with the next h3, get the title put it in the second row, as it is the second subchapter, get the next p tags information and put it in the second rows columns and so on.
So my end goal would be a dataframe with the rows being the subchapters, the columns the informations i need of those subchapters.
For me as a beginner, its so complex and my head burns out so many times..

```
    import numpy as np 
    import pandas as pd 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning"
    respond = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.content, "html.parser")

    # find the subchapter 
    subchapter = soup.find("span", {"id": "Artificial_intelligence"})
    print(subchapter.prettify())

    # get the subchapters text
    prg = []
     for p_tag in subchapter.find_all_next("p")[:3]:
       prg.append(p_tag.get_text())
```

Now i have no idea how i can do it so that i dont have to put an index of [:3], because the next subchapter has only 2 p, so there must be a way i can code this so it works for every subchapter independent of the amount of p tags..
and putting this in a loop so it does this for every subchapter and so on just burns my head, i dont know the next steps..

Answer (score 0):

Because question or better expected result is not that clear, this is just hint how you could iterate the HTML tree and extract what is needed. You could adjust the example to your needs in where to stop, what to extract,... If you improve your question, you will get more specific answers.

---

So approache could be to find all the `<h3>` and its next siblings with `find_next_siblings()`, extracting the information needed and if a stop tag comes up break the loop.

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning"
respond = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(respond.content, "html.parser")

data = []

for chapter in soup.select('h3'):
    d = {'chapter':chapter.span.text,'text':'','links':[],'cite_ref':[]}
    for e in chapter.find_next_siblings():
        if e.name == 'p':
            d['text'] = d.get('text') + ' ' + e.text
            d['links'].extend([a.get('href') for a in e.select('a')])
            d['cite_ref'].extend([c.get('href') for c in e.select('[id^=cite_ref] a')])
        elif e.name in ['h3']:
            break
    data.append(d)
    if d.get('chapter') == 'Statistical Physics':
        break

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
chapter text    links   cite_ref
0   Artificial intelligence As a scientific endeavor, machine learning gr...    [/wiki/Artificial_intelligence, /wiki/Discipli...   [#cite_note-23, #cite_note-aima-24, #cite_note...
1   Data mining Machine learning and data mining often employ...    [/wiki/Data_mining, /wiki/Data_mining, /wiki/D...   [#cite_note-26, #cite_note-27, #cite_note-mi_j...
2   Generalization  The difference between optimization and machi...    [/wiki/Generalization_(learning), /wiki/Deep_l...   [#cite_note-27, #cite_note-mi_jordan_ama-28, #...
3   Statistics  Machine learning and statistics are closely r...    [/wiki/Statistics, /wiki/Statistical_inference...   [#cite_note-27, #cite_note-mi_jordan_ama-28, #...
4   Statistical Physics Analytical and computational techniques deriv...    [/wiki/Deep_neural_network, #cite_note-SP_1-32...   [#cite_note-SP_1-32, #cite_note-SP_2-33]
```

Comment: okay so, this looks not bad. I want it to stop after the chapter "statistical physics" and also, the chapter column should be the index
and then also i need 2 more columns, which are the footnotes and the links so the "hrefs" of the chapters
Also, im not sure enough if im understanding what your for loop exactly does, can you explain it in a simple way?

Comment: mhh, if you print the df.values you see that you get the text from the beginning to the end, only the start point changes for every chapter, but it goes until the end
Its the same for the footnotes or links column, it gets everything until the end, but it should only be for the chapter not every chapter

Comment: That was my bad while editing I skipped the `h3` instead the `h2` from the list of stop tags, but the idea is almost the same.